# Javascript add/remove classes from X elements but 1

Tags: javascript

so I have these flex panels where I add two classes when I click in one of them, but when I click in another I want to remove the classes from the other flexes and apply only on the current flex beeing clicked. The code above is what I came up so far. It works, but is there any other "clean/elegant" way of doing it ?

```
<div class="panels">
    <div class="panel panel1">
      <p>Hey</p>
      <p>Let's</p>
      <p>Dance</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel2">
      <p>Give</p>
      <p>Take</p>
      <p>Receive</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel3">
      <p>Experience</p>
      <p>It</p>
      <p>Today</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel4">
      <p>Give</p>
      <p>All</p>
      <p>You can</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel5">
      <p>Life</p>
      <p>In</p>
      <p>Motion</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Js snippet:

```
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

function toggleOpen(){
    panels.forEach(panel => panel.classList.remove('open','open-active'));
    this.classList.toggle('open');
    this.classList.toggle('open-active');
}
panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
```

Comment: html example???

Comment: "the code above"... there is no code above... please provide your html markup

Comment: Sorry. Html added

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it? Doesn't seem like you really need `toggle`, since you can just use `this.classList.add('open', 'open-active')`, but otherwise what's the problem?

Comment: Nothing wrong, it just doesn´t seem like a "clean" way of doing it, using an outer scoped array inside the toggleOpen function. And yes i was playing with the toggle method and didnt change it to  the "add".  Theres no specific method/event or anything like i could use ?

Comment: If you don't like the cached selection, then you could select inside the handler, like `document.querySelectorAll(".open.open-active")` But this is already very straight forward. Once you change it to `.add()`, it'll be a simple, two line function.

Comment: Hmm i see, ok thanks!

Comment: I'd probably make a reusable function for removing classes from all elements and then adding them to a selected element. https://jsfiddle.net/nLwe61dp/ Making simple utilities like that is probably the cleanest and most flexible way to handle stuff like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could listen to bubbled `click` events on the parent element. With the use of the [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method (FF & Chrome), code can be simplified to this:

```
const panels = document.querySelector('.panels');

panels.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const panel = panels.querySelector('.open');
    if (panel) panel.classList.remove('open', 'open-active');
    e.target.closest('.panel').classList.add('open', 'open-active');
});
```

Or, with a closure that remembers the currently selected panel:

```
(function (panels, panel) {
    panels.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (panel) panel.classList.remove('open', 'open-active');
        (panel = e.target.closest('.panel')).classList.add('open', 'open-active');
    });
})(document.querySelector('.panels'));
```

Comment: Nice that they're in the process of including a `.closest()` method. Not so nice that they chose jQuery's abysmal naming. Something more descriptive like `elem.ascendTo(selector)` or `elem.getAncestor(selector)` or something would've been better, IMO.

Answer (score -1):

Despite you not having provided your HTML, I believe I understand what you're trying to do. I'll give it a shot with jQuery.

With jQuery:

```
let $all = $('.open', '.open-active');
$(".panel").click(function(event) {
    $all.each(function(index, e2) {
        if (!$(event.target).is(e2)) {
            $(e2).removeClass('open', 'open-active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I see no indication that the OP is using jQuery, so I don't know how this is relevant. Besides that, your syntax is invalid and the code won't do what the OP wants.

Comment: My apologies, I figured since no one else answered, I'd give it a shot. and I believe I fixed the syntax issue.

Comment: One more syntax issue, but even after you fix that, the code won't be correct for what the OP is doing.

Comment: I fixed the event.target issue. Forgot it was sending an event and not an element. Is there another issue? And I assumed he wanted to remove the classes for every element except for the one he clicked. He already provided the assumed logic for adding them.

Comment: Yes, the logic is still wrong, and it's still an irrelevant jQuery solution to a non-jQuery question.

Comment: Ok fair enough. But I'm not seeing how the logic is wrong. Could you elaborate? Could at least be a learning experience.

Comment: @qbolt, indeed i´m not using jquery and i still din´t tackle it. I´m currently a newb at js and trying to learn vanilla js. But thanks for your answer !

Comment: `$('.open', '.open-active');` selects all `.open` elements that are a descendant of an `'.open-active'` element. Also, that only selects those that have the class at the time of that selection. It doesn't up date to reflect the `.removeClass`. And the OP wanted to add the classes to the clicked element.